# Is there any method to create + import data directly into postgresql table using csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have to write a script on windows to import .csv files directly into **postgresql** table(Creation and data restore), i searched to many articles on web but nothing impressive.
If any one of you face such kind of situation then please let me know how can you overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance!!
Cheers!!!

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: `COPY` will let you load the data, but how would the database know the data types of each column (assuming it's CSV with header) or whether rows were nullable? It'd have to guess from the first few rows. This is why you have to tell it with `CREATE TABLE` before you load the data. Look at ETL tools like Pentaho Kettle, Talend Studio, CloverETL, etc, and at pgloader / pg_bulkload.